# Проблемы с кодировкой в DENWER

Tags: кодировка, denwer

Все текстовые (`php`) файлы на сайте кодированы в `UTF-8 без BOM` (`NotePad++`). На сайте все отображается как и должно.

Если полностью скопировать сайт на локальную машину и запустить в `DENWER`, то вылезают крокозябры. Если сменить в блокноте кодировку файлов на `ANSI`, то все отображается правильно.

Вопрос: можно ли заставить `DENWER` понимать `UTF-8`? Потому что кодировать все файлы туда-сюда довольно утомительно.

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда нашел ответ, когда уже написал вопрос...

Вопрос решается так: берем /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf, открываем. Ищем строку “AddDefaultCharset windows-1251″ и меняем её на “AddDefaultCharset utf-8″.

Это один из способов.[взял отсюда](http://exclusiveblog.ru/markup/problema-s-utf8-v-denwere).

P.S. Не удаляю вопрос, потому что может кому-нибудь он да поможет.

Comment: ага. только http://localhost/denwer/ после этого будет с неправильной кодировкой :)

Comment: Спасибо очень помог

Comment: Спасибо очень помог